# console application getting close on azure api execution and no error is captured

Tags: c#, azure-form-recognizer

I am using azure form recognizer to extract data from my invoices and the code looks like below,

```
try
{
string endpoint = "https://centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/";//I copied this endpoint from azure portal
string key = "FMKey";
AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(key);
DocumentAnalysisClient client = new DocumentAnalysisClient(new Uri(endpoint), credential);

// sample document
Uri fileUri = new Uri("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/master/curl/form-recognizer/sample-layout.pdf");

AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-layout", fileUri);
                
AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;

foreach (DocumentPage page in result.Pages)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Document Page {page.PageNumber} has {page.Lines.Count} line(s), {page.Words.Count} word(s),");
    Console.WriteLine($"and {page.SelectionMarks.Count} selection mark(s).");

    for (int i = 0; i < page.Lines.Count; i++)
    {
        DocumentLine line = page.Lines[i];
        Console.WriteLine($"  Line {i} has content: '{line.Content}'.");

        Console.WriteLine($"    Its bounding box is:");
        Console.WriteLine($"      Upper left => X: {line.BoundingPolygon[0].X}, Y= {line.BoundingPolygon[0].Y}");
        Console.WriteLine($"      Upper right => X: {line.BoundingPolygon[1].X}, Y= {line.BoundingPolygon[1].Y}");
        Console.WriteLine($"      Lower right => X: {line.BoundingPolygon[2].X}, Y= {line.BoundingPolygon[2].Y}");
        Console.WriteLine($"      Lower left => X: {line.BoundingPolygon[3].X}, Y= {line.BoundingPolygon[3].Y}");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < page.SelectionMarks.Count; i++)
    {
        DocumentSelectionMark selectionMark = page.SelectionMarks[i];

        Console.WriteLine($"  Selection Mark {i} is {selectionMark.State}.");
        Console.WriteLine($"    Its bounding box is:");
        Console.WriteLine($"      Upper left => X: {selectionMark.BoundingPolygon[0].X}, Y= {selectionMark.BoundingPolygon[0].Y}");
        Console.WriteLine($"      Upper right => X: {selectionMark.BoundingPolygon[1].X}, Y= {selectionMark.BoundingPolygon[1].Y}");
        Console.WriteLine($"      Lower right => X: {selectionMark.BoundingPolygon[2].X}, Y= {selectionMark.BoundingPolygon[2].Y}");
        Console.WriteLine($"      Lower left => X: {selectionMark.BoundingPolygon[3].X}, Y= {selectionMark.BoundingPolygon[3].Y}");
    }
}

foreach (DocumentStyle style in result.Styles)
{
    // Check the style and style confidence to see if text is handwritten.
    // Note that value '0.8' is used as an example.

    bool isHandwritten = style.IsHandwritten.HasValue && style.IsHandwritten == true;

    if (isHandwritten && style.Confidence > 0.8)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Handwritten content found:");

        foreach (DocumentSpan span in style.Spans)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"  Content: {result.Content.Substring(span.Index, span.Length)}");
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("The following tables were extracted:");

for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables.Count; i++)
{
    DocumentTable table = result.Tables[i];
    Console.WriteLine($"  Table {i} has {table.RowCount} rows and {table.ColumnCount} columns.");

    foreach (DocumentTableCell cell in table.Cells)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"    Cell ({cell.RowIndex}, {cell.ColumnIndex}) has kind '{cell.Kind}' and content: '{cell.Content}'.");
    }
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

throw;
}
```

but the problem is my console application is getting closed affter this line

```
AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-layout", fileUri);
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

This is the sample code copied from the portal, And I just replace

> endpoint and key

The application is console application and I am developing this on .net framework 4.7.2. I checked the pdf I am providing in the URI and everything looks fine.

Comment: Ensure all the calling functions upto the entry point Main are having "async Task" as part of their signature. Likely your main thread finishes before the azure resource/document has returned, so your console app is ending.

Comment: its just a sample, I was debugging and checking if I am getting some error